# External Data Refresh Failed SharePoint 2013 Excel services with Powerpivot

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, excel, data, refresh

I'm facing the issue with SharePoint 2013 when i Add excel with external data refresh I got the following :

> "External Data Refresh Failed An error occurred while working on the
>   Data Model in the workbook. Please try again.  We were unable to
>   refresh one or more data connections in this workbook.  The following
>   connections failed to refresh"

I've tried with use Appreciation Id and none options in authentication setting but still facing the same issue